# add image to JLabel

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to make a program with an image and 2 buttons namely zoom in and zoom out that will zoom in and zoom out the image.
I am trying to add an image using JLabel but I'm not able to do so.
I have tried using ImageIcon to create an icon and use it in JLabel method setIcon() but the image is not displaying. I have also referred to some codes on StackOverflow but none of them worked for me.

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class Car extends JFrame
{
    JButton zoomIn, zoomOut;
    JLabel img; 
    String url = "C:\\Users\\Misomaniac\\eclipse-workspace\\Chegg\\Desert.jpeg";            // url of image


    public Car() {
        super("Car");                    // title bar text
        setLayout(null);

        zoomIn = new JButton("Zoom in");
        zoomIn.setBounds(150, 250, 100, 30);        // location in Frame
        add(zoomIn);

        zoomOut = new JButton("Zoom out");
        zoomOut.setBounds(280,250,100,30);          // location in Frame
        add(zoomOut);

        img = new JLabel();     
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(url); 

        img.setIcon(icon);  
        img.setBounds(200, 50, 300, 200);           // location in Frame
        add(img);

        zoomIn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    // image will zoom in when this button is clicked
                }
        });

        setVisible(true);  
        setSize(550,400);       // size of window
        setLocation(100,150);   // location of window on monitor
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    }


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new Car();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code works for me. Is your file path correct?

Comment: i have copied the file path from properties, so it should be correct

Comment: Check `getImageLoadStatus()`

Comment: @LakshyaMunjal you say *should* be correct - try it - copy the link and paste it and it will either open or it won't.

Comment: it worked.. actualyy I wrote .jpeg as file extension rather than .jpg

Comment: 1) *"`String url = "C:\\Users\\Misomaniac\\eclipse-workspace\\Chegg\\Desert.jpeg"; // url of image`"* Both the attribute name and the comment, in mentioning 'url' are wrong or at the least misleading. That is a `String` that might represent a `File` path. 2) `setLayout(null);` Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and ..

Comment: ..  borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556). 3) (Ironic, given point 1, but..) Application resources will become embedded resources by the time of deployment, so it is wise to start accessing them as if they were, right now.  An [tag:embedded-resource] must be accessed by URL rather than file.  See the [info. page for embedded resource](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for how to form the URL.